# May a non-Ethiopian Jew celebrate Sigd?

Tags: halacha, minhag, chagim-holidays, ethiopian-beta-israel

Ethiopian Jews recently celebrated their festival of [Sigd](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/187702#.VHIzgZPF-sg), which involves reacceptance of the Torah, communal fasting and feasting, and prayers.

Is it acceptable for someone of a Minhag other than that of the Beta Israel/Ethiopian Jews to celebrate Sigd? I ask because it is a holiday that doesn't exist outside of all non-Ethiopian traditions, but also doesn't conflict with Jewish beliefs. I've been in Israel during Sigd (though I wasn't this year), and wondered about "joining in" with my Ethiopian friends when they celebrated.

Obviously  CYLOR, etc.

Comment: +1, interesting question....I'd never heard of Sigd before seeing this post!

Comment: @Shokhet, the Ethiopian Calendar differs in terms of chagim relative to the common variant among other Jews. They also have a variant of beha"b, which occurs every week (be"h?).

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I may just have to ask some new questions about the Ethiopian calendar, then :) ....live and learn, huh?

Comment: @Shokhet, yup, but the only resource that I know of is Wiki. I doubt that Hebrewbooks (or any other mainstream Eurasian or African Jewish resources) would have much on them.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50879

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a definitive Halakhic answer, but at some level it seems like Sephardic Rabbis are open to this.

[image: The Rishon Lezion Yitchak Yosef on worship stage at Sigd festival]

The Rishon Lezion Yitchak Yosef (son of Ovadia Yosef) went to a Sigd festival and got up on the main worship stage and said the following:

> “I wish to bless you on the occasion of your holiday,” he told the
> worshipers. “There is nothing greater than that there be unity in the
> nation of Israel. Thank God, we have merited that there be an
> ingathering of exiles … . For two thousand years we longed for this
> thing … . Thank God, there are now over six million Jews in the Land
> of Israel.”
>
> Rabbi Yitzhak Yosef used the occasion to remember his late father. “I
> wish to mention my father, Rabbi Ovadia Yosef, who issued the rabbinic
> ruling that the Jews of Ethiopia are Jews in every sense, basing
> himself on the words of the Radbaz (Rabbi David ben Shelomo ibn Zimra)
> and Rabbi (Yaakov) Castro and others,” the Sephardi Chief Rabbi said.

Source: https://www.jewishrhody.com/stories/israels-ethiopian-jewish-community-celebrates-annual-sigd-holiday-in-jerusalem,3042

Comment: Although Ovadia Yosef called blacks "monkeys," he correctly celebrated this Jewish festival, which is a good thing for him to do.

Comment: I believe Ovadia Yosef was quoting the Kuzari and others who make such disparaging remarks.

Comment: You may be right. Sadly, the Kuzari makes many disparaging statements about non-Jews.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Source: People do.

See [this article](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/187702#.VHI7s1WUc8o), where it talks about how Sigd has become an Israeli holiday (on the calendar since 2008), celebrated by both Ethiopians and non-Ethiopians.

However, if you look at the article above, you can see them prostrating, which is a problem according to mainstream Judaism. If joining, you might want to skip that part.

Comment: Are those people joining recognized halachic authorities? If not i dont see how they are relevant

Comment: It seems from the linked article that rabbis would encourage their non-Ethiopian students to join in the festivities.

Comment: @Scimonster I know people do celebrate it, but I was curious if anyone had issued a formal ruling

Comment: @ShmuelBrin http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50879